# Loop/Batch file for extracting all .aac from .m4a files in folder

Tags: command-line, audio, video, ffmpeg, batch

I'm desperate.

I need to extract the `.aac` stream from ~1749 `.m4a` files with `ffmpeg`, but I can't get a batch file working for me and it would take years to do it manually.

This is what I use for single files:

```
ffmpeg -i example.m4a -vn -c:a copy example.acc
```

I don't want to convert the files - I only want to extract the `.aac` audio stream (don't wanna lose more quality).

`ffmpeg -i *.m4a -vn -c:a copy *.acc` isn't working and I don't know how to use for in loops since I'm not a programmer.
All loops I found on the internet aren't working for me.

OS: Windows 7 Professional.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I meant to write ".aac" not ".acc".

Comment: Try something like this and report back your results. Just plug in your source path and the output path accordingly.  `FOR %A IN ("C:\SourcePath\*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%~A" -vn -c:a copy "C:\OutputPath\%~NA.acc"`.   Do this from a command line manually too, not from a batch script and TEST it first too, do not run it against critical files until TESTING is complete.

Comment: Dude, I LOVE YOU. You saved my day.

// FOR %A IN ("*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%~A" -vn -c:a copy "%~NA.aac" //

Was the thing. ffmpeg.exe is in the same folder as the files. :)

Comment: This is why people should always learn some basic programming skills. It's almost 2016 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below examples and just plug in your source path and output path accordingly—I have both implicit and explicit examples below to run as batch or manually from command prompt.

*As usual be sure to test this with test files first though to ensure it works as expected.*

---

### Explicit

**Manual from command line copy and paste**

```
FOR %A IN ("C:\SourcePath\*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%~A" -vn -c:a copy "C:\OutputPath\%~NA.aac"
```

**Run from a batch script**

```
FOR %%A IN ("C:\SourcePath\*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%%~A" -vn -c:a copy "C:\OutputPath\%%~NA.aac"
```

---

### Implicit

**Manual from command line copy and paste**

```
FOR %A IN ("*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%~A" -vn -c:a copy "%~NA.aac"
```

**Run from a batch script**

```
FOR %%A IN ("*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%%~A" -vn -c:a copy "%%~NA.aac"
```

Answer (score 2):

Method 1: open `cmd` and type:

```
FOR %A IN ("C:\SourcePath\*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%~A" -vn -c:a copy "C:\OutputPath\%~NA.aac"
```

Method 2: open `cmd` and type:

```
FOR %A IN ("C:\SourcePath\*.m4a") DO ffmpeg -i "%~A" -vn -acodec copy "C:\OutputPath\%~NA.aac"
```

Both of them work.